# Botão mudar o status

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um código onde o cliente ao clicar no botão, ele vai ativar ou não um usuário, e claro, mudar o status no banco de dados. Até aqui tudo ok. Porém o código tem dois botões, Ativar e Desativar, sendo que inicialmente o botão Desativar fica ocultado por padrão. Veja abaixo:

```
$('button#btn-cancelar').hide();
```

Então no PHP fiz dessa forma:

```
if($jmVagas->StatusVagas == 'A'){
  $botao = "$('button#btn-cancelar').hide();";
}if($jmVagas->StatusVagas == 'N'){
  $botao = "$('button#btn-salvar').hide();";
}
```

Porém ao clicar no botão, ele muda o status no banco corretamente, mas a visualização aparece o mesmo em ambos. Vou postar o código para vocês:

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  //   $('button#btn-cancelar').hide();
  <?php
  echo $visualizarVagas[1];
  ?>

        $('button#btn-salvar').click(function(){
            $('button#btn-salvar').hide();
          $('button#btn-cancelar').show();
          var valor = $(this).attr('value');
           $('button#btn-cancelar').text("Desativado").attr({
              title:"Desativado"
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
          url : "alterar.php?v=N&k="+valor,
          dataType : 'json',
          async : false,
          success : function(msg) {
          }
        });
        });
        $('button#btn-cancelar').click(function(){
            $('button#btn-salvar').show();
        $('button#btn-cancelar').hide();
        var valor = $(this).attr('value');
            $('button#btn-salvar').text("Ativado").attr({
                title:"Ativado"
            });
        jQuery.ajax({
          url : "alterar.php?v=A&k="+valor,
          dataType : 'json',
          async : false,
          success : function(msg) {
          }
        });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
while(...){

    if($jmVagas->StatusVagas == 'A'){
      $botao = "$('button#btn-cancelar').hide();";
    }if($jmVagas->StatusVagas == 'N'){
      $botao = "$('button#btn-salvar').hide();";
    }

         $listar .= "<button class=\"btn btn-xs btn-primary\" id=\"btn-salvar\" value=\"".$jmVagas->IdVagas."\" title=\"Ativado\">Ativado</button>";
         $listar .= "<button class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger\" id=\"btn-cancelar\" value=\"".$jmVagas->IdVagas."\" title=\"Desativado\">Desativado</button>";
}
```

Comment: Por que você não trabalha o hide no success do ajax em vez de colocar o comando do jquery em uma variavel php ?

Comment: Olá Gabriel. Perdoe-me a ignorância, pois não conheço muito bem ajax/jquery. Como faria isso exatamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Array Json exemplo de retorno do php
var myArray = [{
  "nome": "Gabriel",
  "senha": "123",
  "ativo": "Ativado"
}, {
  "nome": "Rodrigues",
  "senha": "1234",
  "ativo": "Desativado"
}, {
  "nome": "Fonseca",
  "senha": "98745",
  "ativo": "Ativado"
}];

// carrega os usuarios na tabela
var table = '';
$.each(myArray, function(key, val) {
  table += '<tr>';
  table += '<td>' + myArray[key].nome + '</td>';
  table += '<td>' + myArray[key].senha + '</td>';
  // verifica se o usuario em questão esta ativado ou não criando um botão para aciona-lo
  if (myArray[key].ativo === "Ativado") {
    table += '<td><button class="btn btn-success" name=' + myArray[key].nome + '>' + myArray[key].ativo + '</button></td>';
  } else {
    table += '<td><button class="btn btn-default" name=' + myArray[key].nome + '>' + myArray[key].ativo + '</button></td>';
  }
  table += '</tr>';
});
// preenche os usuarios dinamicamente na tabela
$("tbody").append(table);

// no click do botao pegar o nome do usuario e a acao dele.
$("button").click(function() {
  var nomeUsuario = $(this).attr("name");
  var acao = $(this).text();
  console.log(nomeUsuario);
  console.log(acao);
  // se o usuario estiver ativo, desative ele, você precisa adicionar um ajax para enviar a acao para o php, pode ser um update where cliente = nomeUsuario.
  if (acao === "Ativado") {
    $(this).text("Desativado").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-default");
  } else {
    $(this).text("Ativado").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Senha</th>
      <th>Ativo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A lógica esta ai, você so precisa adaptar para o seu problema e colocar um ajax para mudar o status no banco de dados.

Comment: Olá Gabriel. Certo. Infelizmente não funcionou. Acredito que seja pq os botões estejam dentro do while() do PHP. Quando clico em ativar no segundo usuário, o botão do primeiro usuário muda conforme o segundo.

Comment: A ideia que tive foi o seguinte: Os botões vem dentro do while() do PHP. Logo os botões terão os mesmos nomes (id="btn-salvar"). Não teria como no jquery criar um array e colocar nesse código tb? ( $('button#btn-salvar').hide(); )

Comment: Jose, não seria boa pratica usar o mesmo `id` para todos, recomendo você diferenciar pelo atributo `name=`, se você ver o teste acima, cada botão fica com o nome do usuario que você quer ativar/desativar

Comment: Olá Gabriel. Desculpe a demora. Estarei efetuando testes e retorno assim que finalizar.

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel. Funcionou!!!